# Redirecionar pagina JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Ao realizar o cadastro do "objeto" em uma JSP, que chama um command que no final chama um outro que faz o redirecionamento para a "listarObjetos".

```
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/controller.do?command=ListarOperacoes");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Só que quando ele retorna para a JSP onde lista os "objetos", na URL esta os parâmetros do "objeto" criado. E se dou um F5 (atualizar) na pagina, ele faz o cadastro novamente.

Preciso zerar a URL quando for redirecionado para a JSP de listar.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/cadastro/Operacoes.jsp");
```

Comment: Acho que você não deve executar um forward e sim um redirect. Então, substituaseu forward por `response.sendRedirect("/url de destino");`

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou ;D